# how to treat a single table as multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across this sql challenge from Hackerrank.com
sample Input :

```
select * from occupation
```

sample output :

```
Name        Occupation     
samantha    doctor
jenny       doctor
julia       actor
maria       actor
jane        actor
meera       singer
priya       singer
ashley      professor
ketty       professor
christeen   professor
```

Output should be :(doctor,professor,singer,actor also order by name)

```
jenny       ashley         meera       jane
samantha    christeen      priya       julia
null        ketty          null        maria
```

What I have tried is :

```
SELECT DECODE(occupation,'doctor',name,NULL   ),DECODE(occupation,'professor',name,NULL),DECODE(occupation,'singer',name,NULL)  ,
DECODE(occupation , 'actor',name,NULL)
FROM occupation ;
```

But it doesnot give me desired result.Also I have tried this :

```
SELECT oc1.name ,
oc2.name,oc3.name,oc4.name
FROM
(SELECT name,occupation FROM occupation WHERE occupation = 'doctor'
) oc1 ,
(SELECT name,occupation FROM occupation WHERE occupation = 'actor'
) oc2 ,
(SELECT name,occupation FROM occupation WHERE occupation = 'singer') oc3,
(SELECT name,occupation FROM occupation WHERE occupation = 'professor')oc4  ,   occupation oc

WHERE 
oc1.occupation= oc.occupation(+)
and oc2.occupation = oc.occupation(+)
AND oc3.occupation       = oc.occupation(+)
AND oc4.occupation       = oc.occupation(+);
```

But it gives duplicate records . Can someone please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT doctor, professor, singer, actor
FROM   (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name ) AS rn
  FROM   occupation o
)
PIVOT ( MAX( name ) FOR Occupation IN (
  'doctor'    AS doctor,
  'actor'     AS actor,
  'singer'    AS singer,
  'professor' AS professor
) )
ORDER BY rn;
```